# How am I able to change this constant?

Tags: swift

How does this code snippet work? Maybe I am missing a fundamental point here but I always thought that  constants are well, constant and the only properties you could modify were variables. How does this compile?

```
  extension MKPointAnnotation {
    static var example: MKPointAnnotation {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Current Stay"
        annotation.subtitle = "Temporary Maryland Abode"
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 20, longitude: -70)
        
        return annotation
    }
}
```

Comment: `title`, `subtitle`, and `coordinate` are properties of `MKPointAnnotation`. Those are declared as `var`s, so this works.

Comment: Ahh, thanks that makes sense.  "let" is just a placeholder in this case then

Comment: MKPointAnnotation is a class, so though annotation is declared as a constant you can still modify properties of it. The let annotation only means a different object of MKPointAnnotation can’t be assigned to it. In case of struct that is declared as a constant you can’t modify properties of it.